# Has there been anything like the Flying Spaghetti Monster originating in the Middle East?

Tags: middle-east

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348379/proper-se-site-to-ask-about-the-flying-spaghetti-monster?noredirect=1#comment1165806_348379) question I like to know, about this topic:

When I was reading about the [Flying Spaghetti Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) and this question came in my mind: Has something similar appeared in the middle east before?  This kind of action happen before, do you know any similar action to the religion in this area of Earth?

> **Update:**
>
> similar action as Not specially satirical religion, but one or more
> movement to create a humankind god for competition with the already
> humankind's gods model, in middle-east geography, which could have fun
> also inside of it like the [Flying Spaghetti Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster).

If yes, what elements of the flying spaghetti monster does it share?

How has it changed since its inception?

Comment: Similar in what way? A satirical religion? A god composed of noodles?

Comment: Not satirical religion, one or more movement to  create a humankind god for competition with the already humankind's gods model, in middle-east geography, also i have updated the Question.

Answer (score 2):

No. The FSM started as an initiative to expose the unfair tax exemption of religious organizations in the US, which has allowed churches to turn into tax-free corporations with huge stadia, private jets, etc. The creation and growth of the FSM was possible because of the US First Amandement, which guarantees freedom of/from religion.

The situation in the Middle East is quite different. Most countries are either officially Islamic theocracies, others are either monarchies or dictatorships aligned with Islamic law. Apostasy is still illegal is all Middle-Eastern Islamic countries (in some it even carries the death penalty):

[image]

Therefore, an initiative like FSM cannot even start in these countries as its very creation would be considered illegal. For this reason, the secular movements in these countries are restricted in the ways they can try to bring about a separation of religion and state. They either rely strongly on social media or need to act individually or in small groups, risking legal and mob persecution. The best known example is the fatwa on Salman Rushdie.

Comment: I know about its prohibition in the middle east, but I like to know about similar movement during the history which have had this kind of features, maybe I must ask in another SE site Which mire related to history?!